# count in twig without for loop

Tags: symfony, twig

I want to total count resuslt. I have already done it like total group result and In total result in one product....

like:-

Total Group of Product = 15

In one group showing 36 product.

In second group showing 56 product.

I want to show total group product result = 36+56 => 92.
without for loop.

twig file:

```
<table>
<h2> Showing {{ templates | length  }} Products</h2>

    {% for groupResults in templates %}
       {% if groupResults.doclist.docs[0].first_product_name is defined %}


            Show all {{ groupResults | length }} results



        <tr>
            <td>
            {{ groupResults.doclist.docs[0].first_product_name }}




            &nbsp;
            {% if groupResults.doclist.numFound > 4 %}
            <a href="{{ path("design_picker_catalog", { "productSlug": groupResults.doclist.docs[0].first_product_slug, "search": searchTerm }) }}" style="float:right">Show all {{ groupResults.doclist.numFound }} results</a>
            {% endif %}
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr> 
        {% set count = 0 %}
        {% for template in groupResults.doclist.docs %}
            <td>
                <a href="{{ path("customer_design_editor", { "templateSlug": template.slug, "productSlug": template.product_slug[0] }) }}">
                    <img src="{{ path("design_template_thumbnail_by_slug", { "slug": template.slug}) }}" alt="" />
                </a>
            </td>
            {% set count = count + 1 %}
        {% endfor %}
        {% if count < 4 %}
        {% for i in count..3 %}
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
    {% else %}
    {% endif %}     
    {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Can you edit your post to make it easier to be understood? I don't really get what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about:

```
{% set totalCount = firstGroup|length + secondGroup|length %}
```

Comment: hey thanks for reply but it's not only two productGroup I have many productGroup. you can see this in my code...

Comment: Setup a var for your total and then for each group just call {% set totalcount = totalcount + group|length %} then you don't have to loop inside each group. Of course, the count/total could be done before twig (php)